# Getting an error while installing mongodb driver

Tags: mongodb

I am getting an error while installing mongodb driver to connect it with node js. The error says -

npm ERR! code ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE
npm ERR! error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rakes\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-05T15_17_34_808Z-debug-0.log

can anyone help me to get rid out of this ?

I have been trying to solve, watching videos on youtube however I could not find any video helpful so please help me with this.

Comment: What's in the said log ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did get similar error once and was able to resolve it by doing this.

- Go to this address << C:\Users\tarun >> [tarun is my username, for you it's whatever your user name is]
- you will see a file with the name of << .npmrc >>
- delete it and try again